# Como manter um $_POST ná página

Tags: php, mysql, formulário, post

Eu tenho um sistema de perguntas,e implementei nele um form onde as pessoas escolhem qual área vão responder:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="perguntas.php">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>SELECIONE O QUESTIONÁRIO</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="select" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Selects</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10">
        <select class="form-control"  name="sub_grupo" id="sub_grupo">
          <option value="100">SETOR 1</option>
          <option value="200">SETOR 2</option>
          <option value="300">SETOR 3</option>
          <option value="400">SETOR 4</option>
          <option value="500">SETOR 5</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">RESPONDER</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Na página  de `perguntas perguntas.php` eu recebo o post com o valor do setor e gravo em uma variável:

```
$sub_grupo = $_POST['sub_grupo'];
```

Ai a pergunta aparece com meus select's e funciona perfeitamente,a duvida é:

Quando o usuário responde a pergunta e vai para a próxima a página atualiza e com isso limpa a variável do post fazendo que o sistema de erros:

> Notice: Undefined index: $sub_grupo in
>   /var/www/html/checklistlojas/setores/teste/perguntas.php on line 9

O que eu poderia fazer para não dar mais esse erro ?

Desde já grato a todos.

Segue um exemplo de select que uso com esse $_POST:

```
$query_pergs = mysql_query("SELECT 
                                COUNT(rp.id)  AS TOTAL_PERG      
                                FROM 
                                 relacaoperg AS rp 
                                 INNER JOIN perguntas AS p   ON rp.id_pergunta = p.perg_id
                                 INNER JOIN area      AS a   ON rp.id_area     = a.area_id
                                 INNER JOIN sub_area  AS sb  ON rp.id_subgrupo = sb.sub_area_cod
                                 WHERE 
                                 a.area_id     ='$area' 
                                AND sb.sub_area_cod='$sub_grupo'");
                                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_pergs)) {
                                $totalpergunta  = $row["TOTAL_PERG"];
                                }
```

Tentei usar SESSION desta forma,mais não deu certo:

```
  @session_start();

  $_SESSION["sub_grupo"] = $_POST['sub_grupo'];
    $sub_grupo = $_SESSION["sub_grupo"];
```

Pessoal, 
 Para tentar ajudar segue meus códigos completos:

INDEX.PHP:

```
<?php 
 include("conexao.php");
  //PERGUNTAS
  $teste_count_perg = mysql_query("SELECT 
                                    COUNT(id_pergunta) AS TOTAL
                                     FROM relacaoperg 
                                      WHERE id_area      = 100
                                        AND id_subgrupo  = 100");
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($teste_count_perg)) { 
                                                      $total_perg = $row["TOTAL"]; 
                                                                        }
 //RESPOSTAS
  $query_count_resp = mysql_query("SELECT 
                                    COUNT(resp_resposta) AS TOTAL 
                                     FROM respostas 
                                      WHERE resp_loja         = 2 
                                        AND resp_questionario = 5
                                        AND resp_area         = 100 
                                        AND resp_subgrupo     = 100
                                        AND resp_usuario NOT  IN ( '37', '38', '39','40','1')");
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_count_resp)) { 
                                                       $total_resp = $row["TOTAL"]; 
                                                                        }

?>
<?php
// A sessão precisa ser iniciada em cada página diferente
if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
// Verifica se não há a variável da sessão que identifica o usuário
if (!isset($_SESSION['usu_login'])) {
  // Destrói a sessão por segurança
  session_destroy();
  // Redireciona o visitante de volta pro login
  header("Location: ../../logout.php"); exit;
}
?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="pt-br" xml:lang="pt-br">
<head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <title>#</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/css/style.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/css/datatables.css">
            <script src="includes/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="includes/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script src="includes/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
            <script src="includes/js/datatables.js"></script> 
            <script>function funcao1(){ alert("Atenção ! todas as perguntas foram respondidas !"); } </script>
    </head>
<body>
   <div class="container">

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" ></a>
    </div>
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
      <?php
    if ($total_perg == $total_resp) {
      echo"<ul class='nav navbar-nav'>";
      echo"<li><a href='#' onclick='funcao1()'>COMPORTAMENTO E HIGIENE PESSOAL <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok' aria-hidden='true'></span></a></li>";
          echo"</ul>";
        echo"</li>";
      echo"</ul>";
       } else {
           echo"<ul class='nav navbar-nav'>";
            echo"<li><a href='comportamento.php'>COMPORTAMENTO E HIGIENE PESSOAL</a></li>";
          echo"</ul>";
        echo"</li>";
      echo"</ul>";
      }
      ?>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="perguntas.php">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>SELECIONE O QUESTIONÁRIO</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="select" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Selects</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10">
        <select class="form-control"  name="sub_grupo" id="sub_grupo">
          <option value="100"<?php echo ($_POST['sub_grupo'] == "100") ? " selected=\"selected\"" : ""; ?>>SETOR 1</option>
          <option value="200">SETOR 2</option>
          <option value="300">SETOR 3</option>
          <option value="400">SETOR 4</option>
          <option value="500">SETOR 5</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">RESPONDER</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>


<table class="table table-striped table-hover ">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>SUBAREA</th>
      <th>PERGUNTAS</th>
      <th>RESPOSTAS</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>COMPORTAMENTO E HIGIENE PESSOAL</td>
      <td><?php echo"$total_perg"; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo"$total_resp"; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ATENDIMENTO AO CLIENTE</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ACONDICIONAMENTO</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>7</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

PERGUNTAS.PHP :

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_erros',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

 include("conexao.php");
  @session_start();   
    $id_usuario = $_SESSION['usu_id'];
    $loja       = $_SESSION['usu_loja_id'];
    $area       = $_SESSION['usu_setor'];
    $quest      = $_SESSION['quest'];

$_SESSION['sub_grupo'] = $_POST["sub_grupo"];
   $sub_grupo = $_SESSION['sub_grupo']; 

  if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
    $loja         = $_GET ["loja"];
    $id_usuario   = $_GET ["id_usuario"]; 
    $questionario = $_GET ["questionario"];
    $area         = $_GET ["area"];
    $idpergunta   = $_GET ["pergunta"];   
    $resp         = $_GET ["resp"]; 
    $datacad      = $_GET ["data_cad"]; 
    $nro_pergunta = $_GET ["nro_pergunta"];


$sql_select_insert = mysql_query("SELECT *  
      FROM respostas 
        WHERE 
        resp_loja='$loja'
        AND resp_usuario='$id_usuario'
        AND resp_questionario='$questionario'
        AND resp_area ='$area'
        AND resp_subgrupo='$sub_grupo'  
        AND resp_pergunta_id='$idpergunta'"); 
  if(mysql_num_rows($sql_select_insert)==0) {
$sql_insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO respostas 
                                            (resp_id,
                                           resp_loja,
                                        resp_usuario,
                                   resp_questionario,
                                           resp_area,
                                       resp_subgrupo,
                                    resp_pergunta_id,
                                       resp_resposta,
                                           resp_data,
                                         resp_status)
                                  VALUES 
                                                 ('',
                                             '$loja',
                                       '$id_usuario',
                                     '$questionario',
                                             '$area',
                                        '$sub_grupo',
                                       '$idpergunta',
                                             '$resp',
                                          '$datacad',
                                               '1')") 
                              or die (mysql_error());
                   mysql_query($sql_insert,$conexao); 
                                                   }   
                                            } else {

                                                   }

$query_pergs = mysql_query("SELECT 
                                COUNT(rp.id)  AS TOTAL_PERG      
                                FROM 
                                 relacaoperg AS rp 
                                 INNER JOIN perguntas AS p   ON rp.id_pergunta = p.perg_id
                                 INNER JOIN area      AS a   ON rp.id_area     = a.area_id
                                 INNER JOIN sub_area  AS sb  ON rp.id_subgrupo = sb.sub_area_cod
                                 WHERE 
                                 a.area_id     ='$area' 
                                AND sb.sub_area_cod='$sub_grupo'");
                                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_pergs)) {
                                $totalpergunta  = $row["TOTAL_PERG"];
                                }

$query_count_resp = mysql_query("SELECT 
                                    COUNT(resp_resposta) AS TOTAL 
                                     FROM respostas 
                                      WHERE resp_loja         = '$loja ' 
                                        AND resp_questionario = '$quest'
                                        AND resp_area         = '$area' 
                                        AND resp_subgrupo     = '$sub_grupo'
                                        AND resp_usuario NOT  IN ( '37', '38', '39','40','1')");
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_count_resp)) { 
                                                       $total_resp = $row["TOTAL"]; 
                                                                        }

  if (isset($_GET['nro_pergunta'])) $nro_pergunta = $_GET['nro_pergunta'] + 1 ;
       else $nro_pergunta = 1;

if ($total_resp  == $totalpergunta) {
// echo '<script>alert(\'Todas as perguntas foram respondidas!\');parent.location =\'index.php\';</script>';
} else {

}
?>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>#</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/css/datatables.css">
  <script src="includes/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="includes/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="includes/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="includes/js/datatables.js"></script> 
  <script language=javascript>    
         document.onkeydown = function () { 
           switch (event.keyCode) {
             case 116 :  
                event.returnValue = false;
                event.keyCode = 0;           
                return false;             
              case 82 : 
                if (event.ctrlKey) {  
                   event.returnValue = false;
                  event.keyCode = 0;             
                  return false;
           }
         }
     } 
  </script>
  </head> 
<body>
<div class="container">

<?php
echo"$sub_grupo";
$query_count_totresp = mysql_query("SELECT 
              count(r.resp_id)  AS TOTRESP
           FROM 
              respostas AS r
           WHERE 
                 r.resp_status       = 1  and
                 r.resp_loja         = 2  and
                 r.resp_questionario = 1  and
                 r.resp_area         = 100 and 
                 r.resp_subgrupo     = '$sub_grupo'") ;

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_count_totresp)) {
    $respondidas  = $row["TOTRESP"];
};

$query_count = mysql_query("SELECT 
       COUNT(rp.id)  AS TOTAL_PERG      
           FROM 
              relacaoperg AS rp 
    INNER JOIN perguntas AS p   ON rp.id_pergunta = p.perg_id
    INNER JOIN area      AS a   ON rp.id_area     = a.area_id
    INNER JOIN sub_area  AS sb  ON rp.id_subgrupo = sb.sub_area_cod
          WHERE 
    a.area_id='$area' AND sb.sub_area_cod='$sub_grupo'");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_count)) {
    $totalpergunta  = $row["TOTAL_PERG"];
    }

     $query_questionario = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questionario WHERE quest_nome='$quest'");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_questionario)) {
    $questionario = $row["quest_id"];
    }

$query_pesquisa = mysql_query("SELECT 
       rp.id            AS ORDEM,
       a.area_id        AS AREA,
       sb.sub_area_cod  AS SUBGRUPO,
       sb.sub_area_nome AS DESC_SUBGRUPO,
       p.perg_id        AS ID_PEGUNTA,
       p.perg_desc      AS DESC_PERGUNTA,
       rp.foto          AS FOTO          
           FROM 
              relacaoperg AS rp 
    INNER JOIN perguntas AS p   ON rp.id_pergunta = p.perg_id
    INNER JOIN area      AS a   ON rp.id_area     = a.area_id
    INNER JOIN sub_area  AS sb  ON rp.id_subgrupo = sb.sub_area_cod
          WHERE 
    a.area_id='$area' AND sb.sub_area_cod='$sub_grupo'  LIMIt $nro_pergunta ");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_pesquisa)) {
    $ordem          = $row["ORDEM"];
    $area           = $row["AREA"];
    $subgrupo       = $row["SUBGRUPO"];
    $descsubgrupo   = $row["DESC_SUBGRUPO"];
    $idpergunta     = $row["ID_PEGUNTA"];
    $descpergunta   = $row["DESC_PERGUNTA"];
    $foto           = $row["FOTO"];
    }
    ?>
  <div class="container-fluid">
<form class="form-horizontal" action="perguntas.php?nro_pergunta=<?php  echo $nro_pergunta; ?>" method="GET">
  <fieldset>
<div class="panel panel-danger"><div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title"></h3></div><div class="panel-body">
<?php
echo"<button id='button' type='next' name='next' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'>PULAR</button>&nbsp;";
$query_nav = mysql_query("SELECT 
                                     p.perg_id        AS ID_PEGUNTA   
                                  FROM 
                                     relacaoperg AS rp 
                                     INNER JOIN perguntas AS p   ON rp.id_pergunta = p.perg_id
                                     INNER JOIN area      AS a   ON rp.id_area     = a.area_id
                                     INNER JOIN sub_area  AS sb  ON rp.id_subgrupo = sb.sub_area_cod
                                  WHERE 
                                     a.area_id='$area' AND sb.sub_area_cod='$sub_grupo'  LIMIT $nro_pergunta ");
                                     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_nav)) {
                                     $perg_id   = $row["ID_PEGUNTA"];
                                     $sub = 1;
                                     $voltar=$perg_id - $sub;
                                   echo"<a href='perguntas.php?nro_pergunta=$voltar' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'>$perg_id</a>&nbsp;";
                                    }                         
    ?> 
      </div>
</div>
<legend><b>Pergunta <?php echo"$ordem";?> de <?php echo"$totalpergunta";?> | <?php echo"$descsubgrupo";?></b></legend>
    <?php
     $data_cad = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
     echo"<input type='hidden' name='loja'         id='loja'         value='$loja'>";
     echo"<input type='hidden' name='id_usuario'   id='id_usuario'   value='$id_usuario'>";
     echo"<input type='hidden' name='questionario' id='questionario' value='$questionario'>";
     echo"<input type='hidden' name='area'         id='area'         value='$area'>";
     echo"<input type='hidden' name='nro_pergunta' id='nro_pergunta' value='$nro_pergunta'>";     
     echo"<input type='hidden' name='data_cad'     id='data_cad'     value='$data_cad'>";
     echo"<input type='hidden' name='pergunta'     id='pergunta'     value='$idpergunta'>";
    ?>

       <?php
$sql_pergsn = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM respostas WHERE 
           resp_loja='$loja'
       AND resp_usuario='$id_usuario'
       AND resp_area ='$area'
       AND resp_pergunta_id ='$idpergunta'
       AND resp_subgrupo='$sub_grupo'
       AND resp_questionario='$questionario'");

     if(mysql_num_rows ($sql_pergsn) == 0 )
      {
     echo"<div class='form-group'>";
      echo"<center><h4><label> $descpergunta</label></h4></center>";
      echo"<div class='col-lg-10'>";
        echo"<div class='radio'><label><input type='radio' name='resp' id='optionsRadios1' value='5'>OTIMO        </label></div>";
        echo"<div class='radio'><label><input type='radio' name='resp' id='optionsRadios2' value='3'>BOM      </label></div>";
        echo"<div class='radio'><label><input type='radio' name='resp' id='optionsRadios3' value='2'>REGULAR         </label></div>";
        echo"<div class='radio'><label><input type='radio' name='resp' id='optionsRadios3' value='1'>RUIM         </label></div>";
        echo"<div class='radio'><label><input checked type='radio' name='resp' id='optionsRadios4' value='0'>NAO APLICADO </label></div>";
        echo"</div>";
      echo"</div>";
      echo"<center>";
     echo"<div class='form-group'>";
       echo"<div class='col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2'>";
        echo"<button id='button' type='submit' name='submit' class='btn btn-danger'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span> Responder</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
       echo"</div>";
    echo"</div>";
    } else  {
    echo"<div class='form-group'>";
      echo"<div class='col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2'>";
            echo"<br>";
            echo"<div class='alert alert-dismissible alert-danger'>";
            echo"<strong>ATENÇÃO! </strong>Você já respondeu essa pergunta.";
            echo"<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'></button>";
            echo"</div>";  
            echo"</div>";  
        echo"<button id='button' type='next' name='next' class='btn btn-danger'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right'></span> Próxima</button><br />";
    echo"</center>";
    }
   ?> 
  </fieldset>
 </form>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></span></a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalResp" ><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-saved'></span>  Respondidas</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalRegra"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign'></span> Regra</a></li>
         <li><a href="index.php"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign'></span> Sair</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav> 
<center><div class="panel panel-danger"><div class="panel-heading">#</div></div></center>
</div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="modalResp">
              <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Respostas</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
              <?php
$query_modal = mysql_query("SELECT 
                    p.perg_desc AS PERGUNTA,
                    r.resp_resposta    AS RESPOSTA
                    FROM respostas AS r
                    INNER JOIN perguntas AS p ON r.resp_pergunta_id = p.perg_id
                    WHERE  
                     resp_loja='$loja'
                     AND resp_usuario='$id_usuario'
                     AND resp_area ='$area'
                     AND resp_subgrupo='$sub_grupo'
                     AND resp_questionario='$questionario'")or die(mysql_error());

                  if (empty($query_modal)) {
                  echo "Nenhum registro encontrado.";
                  }
                  ?>

              <table class='datatable table table-hover table-bordered table-responsiv'>
            <thead>
             <tr>
               <th>PERGUNTA</th>
               <th>RESPOSTA</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
           <?php
              echo"<tbody>";   
              while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_modal)) {
              echo" <tr>";
               echo"<td>".$row['PERGUNTA']."</td>";
                echo"<td >".$row['RESPOSTA']."</td>";
              echo" </tr>";

            }   
           echo"  </tbody>";
          echo" </table>";

         ?>

                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="modal fade" id="modalRegra">
              <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Regra de pontuação</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
             <tr>
               <th>Descrição</th>
               <th>Nota</th>
               <th>Ocorrencias</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
             <tr>
               <td>Ótimo</td>
               <td>5</td>
               <td>Sem ocorrências </td>
             </tr>
               </tbody>
               <tbody>
             <tr>
              <td>Regular</td>
                <td>3</td>
              <td>02 ocorrências</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
               <tbody>
             <tr>
                <td>Ruim</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>03 ocorrências</td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
              <td> N/A</td>
              <td>Não se aplica</td>
              <td>Não se aplica</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.datatable').dataTable({
        "sPaginationType": "bs_full"
      }); 
      $('.datatable').each(function(){
        var datatable = $(this);
        // SEARCH - Add the placeholder for Search and Turn this into in-line form control
        var search_input = datatable.closest('.dataTables_wrapper').find('div[id$=_filter] input');
        search_input.attr('placeholder', 'Search');
        search_input.addClass('form-control input-sm');
        // LENGTH - Inline-Form control
        var length_sel = datatable.closest('.dataTables_wrapper').find('div[id$=_length] select');
        length_sel.addClass('form-control input-sm');
      });
    });
  </script>   
</body>
</html>


Mais alguma dica?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neste caso, para não apresentar o erro, você pode fazer uma verificação no `$_POST` e gravar em sessão na página `perguntas.php`:

```
session_start();

$sub_grupo = null;
if (isset($_POST['sub_grupo'])) {
   $sub_grupo = $_POST['sub_grupo'];
   $_SESSION['sub_grupo'] = $sub_grupo;
}
```

E para a sua outra view (de retorno), você pode retornar os dados do POST:

```
<?php
   session_start();
   //inicia a variável nula
   $return = array('sub_grupo' => null); 
   if ($_SESSION['sub_grupo']) {
      //como a session também é um array, basta passar o tipo: `$_SESSION` 
      $return = $_SESSION;
      //(opcional) aqui eu removo a sessão depois de armazenar numa variável de retorno
      unset($_SESSION['sub_grupo']);
   }
?>
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="perguntas.php">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>SELECIONE O QUESTIONÁRIO</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="select" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Selects</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10">
        <select class="form-control"  name="sub_grupo" id="sub_grupo">
          <option value="100"<?php echo ( $return['sub_grupo'] == "100") ? " selected=\"selected\"" : ""; ?>>SETOR 1</option>
          <option value="200"<?php echo ( $return['sub_grupo'] == "200") ? " selected=\"selected\"" : ""; ?>>SETOR 2</option>
          <option value="300"<?php echo ( $return['sub_grupo'] == "300") ? " selected=\"selected\"" : ""; ?>>SETOR 3</option>
          <option value="400"<?php echo ( $return['sub_grupo'] == "400") ? " selected=\"selected\"" : ""; ?>>SETOR 4</option>
          <option value="500"<?php echo ( $return['sub_grupo'] == "500") ? " selected=\"selected\"" : ""; ?>>SETOR 5</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">RESPONDER</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

**Obs:** recomenda-se utilizar a função `session_start()`, sempre no início da header de todas as páginas que houver sessão. Nunca depois de código HTML. Até se possível em um arquivo a parte, para separar a camada da view.

Comment: Como assim,não entendi bem,porque se eu entendi bem ai no seu exemplo esta setando o post na própria pagina,e minha perguntas ficam em outra,poderia me explicar melhor ?

Comment: Amigo, ele disse que a página vai ser atualizada, ou redirecionada, se não usar SESSÃO ou Cookies, o valor vai ser perdido. Não se entendi bem o que ele quer, mas acredito que seja uma mistura da minha com a sua solução :D

Comment: @session_start();

  $_SESSION["sub_grupo"] = $_POST['sub_grupo'];
    $sub_grupo = $_SESSION["sub_grupo"];

Comment: Eu editei a resposta, eu costumo passar tudo na mesma página, foi mal, daí nem precisaria de sessão. Se você quiser algo mais bem feito, procure se informar sobre [flash messages](https://github.com/plasticbrain/PhpFlashMessages), que tem modelos melhores para esse tipo de implementação.

Comment: Hoje em dia, a maioria dos "posts" são feitos via ajax, de forma assíncrona,  o que evita a necessidade de atualizar ou dar `refresh` na página.

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas,mais continuo sem sucesso.

Comment: Consigui resolver estudando a fundo a dica do @Ivan Ferrer .

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução é usar SESSION, http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.session.php.

Ex:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["sub_grupo"]=5;
```

Na outra página, o valor vai estar disponivel:

```
session_start(); 
echo $_SESSION["sub_grupo"];
```

Comment: Seria isso ? $_SESSION["sub_grupo"]=$_POST['sub_grupo']; , e como eu colocaria nos meus select's ?

Comment: Na verdade SESSION só serve para que uma "variavel" persista depois que o usuário acesse outra página do teu site (por alguns dias/hora ou minutos, não sei bem). Você pode ver isso como um jeito de definir "variáveis globais" para um determinado usuário. Agora, o resto da lógica, acredito que fique da mesma forma.

Comment: Não entendi a pergunta com relação ao Select, você quer que ele aparece em todas as páginas com a opção marcada?

Comment: É assim: na minha pagina tem varios selects (mysql) e eu uso esse $_POST neles,eu criando uma session,como faria para incluir esse valor em meus selects ?

Comment: Como assim incluir nos selects? deixar o select "selecionado" no valor postado anteriormente.

Comment: implementei um exemplo de select que estou usando na pergunta

Comment: Tentei assim,mais sem exito:   @session_start();

  $_SESSION["sub_grupo"] = $_POST['sub_grupo'];
    $sub_grupo = $_SESSION["sub_grupo"];

Comment: AH, tu fala SELECT de SQL e não do elemento do HTML. pera ae

Comment: antes dessa SQL q você postou, faça isso: $sub_grupo = $_SESSION["sub_grupo"]; e pronto, vai existir a variavel "sub_grupo"

Comment: Mais já teste assim:   $_SESSION["sub_grupo"] = $_POST['sub_grupo'];
    $sub_grupo = $_SESSION["sub_grupo"]; e com aspas simples também:   $_SESSION['sub_grupo'] = $_POST['sub_grupo'];
    $sub_grupo = $_SESSION['sub_grupo'];

Comment: Isso foge um pouco da pergunta original. Você tem o valor, você pode usar ele na query, mas não consegue, provavelmente há algum erro de sintaxe, tenta debugar teu script, veja como a query é gerada.

Comment: Só uma observação, o uso de arroba `@` antes de uma função, é uma má prática, para disfarçar um erro, uma espécie de gambiarra, um código maduro e bem feito, não necessita disso.